# phase between the input voltage and the output voltage?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor

If I have this circuit, how can I calculate the phase between the input voltage and the output voltage (capacitor voltage)?
Knowing that the signal frequency is 1kHz

[image: rc circuit]

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you need to add to your question what you have tried.

Comment: Is not homework, I was just guessing that I know how to calculate the phase difference between the current and the voltage, but no between the Vi and Vout? Guess asking here would be faster

Comment: Do you understand phasors and/or differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the transfer function of this circuit is given by:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{out}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}}=\frac{1}{1+\omega\text{CRj}}\tag1$$

So, taking the \$\arg\$ on both sides gives:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(\frac{1}{1+\omega\text{CRj}}\right)=\arg\left(1\right)-\arg\left(1+\omega\text{CRj}\right)=$$
$$0-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{CR}}{1}\right)=-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)\tag2$$

So, at \$\omega=2\pi\cdot1000\$ we get:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(2000\pi\text{j}\right)\right)=-\arctan\left(2000\pi\cdot1000\cdot47\cdot10^{-9}\right)=$$
$$-\arctan\left(\frac{47 \pi }{500}\right)\approx-0.287148\tag3$$

Comment: thankss for the help

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive way is to compute the impedance ratio of the 2 parts as the current is shared and voltage Vin=I*Z for impedance of both together.

The impedance is \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi f C}=X_c(f)=R\$ this 1st order pole output is at half-power = -3dB =0.707 of Vin as the phase is now shifted 45 degrees or 50% of the 90 deg target. But towards that target, the attenuation is huge from the impedance ratio.

**A 1st order filter slope = -3dB per octave (2f) and -20dB per decade.**

attenuation [dB] = 20 log Vo/Vi, so 1= 0 dB

For practical numbers, 1 decade up and down from this breakpoint it is about 84 deg and 5 deg respectively.

Here graph is at 10 dB /decade below and 0 to -90 degree phase shift below.

[image]

[Simulation in browser](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%2047778.98274364548%0AO%20352%2080%20464%2080%200%0Ag%20352%20208%20352%20240%200%0Ar%20192%2080%20352%2080%200%201000%0Ac%20352%2080%20352%20208%200%204.7000000000000004e-8%200%0A170%20192%2080%20160%2080%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ao%204%2032%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%200%2032%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%201%20-1%0A)

The other answer shows the mathematical approach.

Comment: thankss for the help